# How to render a form partial in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

> undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#:0x000001080edfe0>

I am trying to render a form within a template page with:

```
<%= form_for @vehicle, html: { class: "f_grp" }, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= render "vehicles", locals: { f: f } %>
<% end %>
```

The file is loading. But I'm getting an undefined method on `f` error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You only use `:locals` when you use `:partial`.

Either of these are correct:

```
<%= render partial: 'vehicles', locals: { f: f } %>
```

Or (as of Rails 2.3):

```
<%= render 'vehicles', f: f %>
```

Your version, which combines both, creates a local called `locals` and sets its value to a hash containing `f: FormBuilder...`.

It's worth noting that the only reason to still use `locals:` is when you use `render :collection`.